# Cache Playlists using CocoaLibSpotify IOS

Tags: ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I am loading all the playlists for a user at startup and i would like to cache the playlist tracks after the playlists are done loading. Does CocoaLibSpotify already cache the playlists or is there something else i would need to do? I am not looking to mark the playlist tracks for offline mode, just cache the playlists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, metadata is cached for faster loading next time. You should find that playlists load a lot faster the next time your application runs.